# Iterator pointing to empty element of array

Tags: arrays, c++11, iterator, min

I am just wondering whether in an array which has elements, but is not full of elements, e.g :

```
std::array<int, 5> foo;
foo[0] = 4;
foo[1] = 2;
foo[2] = 3;
```

will foo.end() still point to the last element + 1 or will it point to the value at foo[3]?

My context is that I am trying to find the minimum value location of an array which only sometimes has all the elements assigned. Some example code is below:

```
int min_loc = std::min_element(foo.begin(), foo.end()) - foo.begin();
```

Will this extract min_loc = 1? Or will it find 0 at the undefined elements in the array and assign those as the minimum location?

If so, should I define the line above as:

```
int min_loc = std::min_element(foo.begin(), foo.end() - 2) - foo.begin();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no holes in `foo`. Elements you haven't assigned to still exist, they are just uninitialized, containing random garbage. `foo.end()` still points one past `foo[4]`. Your first `std::min_element` call exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized objects.

Comment: Okay thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1** :

Fill all elements in array with std::numeric_limits::max()

**Solution 2:**

If you don't know the size odthe array, use dynamic sized container => vector:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
foo.push_back(4);
foo.push_back(2);
foo.push_back(3);

int min_loc = std::distance(std::begin(v), std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v)));
```

Comment: Thank you, although my highest priority is performance and therefore having a static size array (which gets passed around multiple functions), might be better than an unknown vector size? Think it will be cheaper for me to do : foo.begin() + array_offset as the second limit.

Comment: @A.Lillystone A reference to an array is no easier to pass around than a reference to a vector. Depending on how sparse your data is, copies of `vector`s may be faster than copies of `array`s. Given that, your highest priority should be *correctness*, because `int main() { return 0; }` is going to beat out whatever you program currently is on performance